# Titanium Appcelerator Plugin

Tags: plugins, osx-lion, ios-simulator, coffeescript, titanium

I'm using Titanium appcelerator on Mac OSX Lion and I am trying to configure it to compile coffeescript files on the build.  I have followed the instructions from https://github.com/billdawson/ti_coffee_plugin.  My problem is whenever I try to run my app in the emulator in any envirornment (Android or iphone) I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Build Failed (Missing Plugins Directory)
```

It seems to expect my plugins to be in my local ~/Documents/Titanium Studio Workspace/testCoffee as well as ~/Library/Titanium Support/plugins directory.  I tried copying them over but that caused different problems.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with this too, but I got past missing plugins directory by adding a "1.0" folder inside the plugins directory above the plugin.py file.  I didn't see it needing a plugin file in the workspace, but there is ambiguity whether it looks in global or user Library directory, or perhaps both, I don't know how that works in OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I have a template project to work with Coffeescript over Titanium: [titanium-coffeescript](https://github.com/alfonsocora/titanium-coffeescript)

All the code should be written to the `coffee` folder. Then, when running `rake`, all the javascript files are generated into the `Resources` folder used by Titanium. Then, you can run the app from Titanium Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You actually had the answer to this particular problem in your question.  (Clarification added in brackets)

> I tried copying them over [to Titanium Support/plugins] but that caused different problems.

When I used this on OS X, I believe the proper folder structure with the file was `~/Library/Titanium Support/plugins/ti_coffee_plugin/1.0/plugin.py`

I came back to this because I'm trying to get this set up on Ubuntu, so I just wanted to add that for people out there trying to work in this system.  The proper folder setup for Ubuntu is: `~/.titanium/plugins/ti_coffee_plugin/1.0`

In both cases, you first have to go to that titanium support folder and `mkdir -p plugins/ti_coffee_plugin/1.0` from a fresh install of Titanium, since it doesn't create the plugins folder by default.